# iframe play & thumbnail function

Tags: javascript, beginner, dom, video

This is quite a simple function, but I just wanted some opinions on it, like is this the correct way to run a function and check if an element exists or not?

```
const button = document.querySelector('.js-brand-video--thumbnail')
const iframe = document.querySelector('.js-brand-video--iframe')

function playVideo () {
  if (button) {
    button.classList.add('video-poster--hidden')
    iframe.src = iframe.getAttribute('data-src')
  }
}

if (button)
  button.addEventListener('click', playVideo, false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) can return `null`. So while you are checking `button`, you aren't checking for `iframe`. You will possibly get `Assigning property src to undefined` or something like that.

`classList` is one of the newer properties. If you see your code being used in older browsers, you should watch out. Check the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility) for support.

A practice used by jQuery and other libraries is to use sets. It's where you put results in an array and for each item, operate on it. If no items are on the set, no code executes.

```
// Use querySelectorAll to get elements. querySelectorAll returns a
// NodeList. To use array methods, we convert it to an array with
// slice.
const buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-brand-video--thumbnail'));
const iframes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-brand-video--iframe'));

// forEach runs the callback for each item in the array. If no items
// reside, no loop runs, therefore no code executes.
button.forEach(function(button){
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    button.classList.add('video-poster--hidden')
    iframe.forEach(function(iframe){
      iframe.getAttribute('data-src');
    }); 
  }, false)
});
```